# How to secure communication from a client agent to a server via HTTP REST

Tags: rest, http, security

I am looking to build a reporting agent from client server nodes to a main analytics/reporting dashboard and am trying to figure out the best way to secure the communication without needing to build a client ID/client secret for each server node.

What would be the best way to do this? When a new client server node is brought online, it can start reporting, and not require manual authentication intervention?

Comment: What is your authentication/authorization model? Do you just want to allow any client? What is the threat model you are trying to secure against? As it stands this post is unanswerable